# App crashes when loading networkimage in gridview

Tags: flutter

I am creating a gridview of images using future but during scrolling of gridview app crashes and there is not error but just

## Lost connection to device.

## Exited (sigterm)

the images reappear and disappear when scrolling up and down .

i have tried using image.network , cached network image , fadein image but not working . i have also limit my image request to 40 but also it crashes . image size are only 20-100 kb range .

```
// future function to load subcategory json
Future<subcategory> fetchallsubcategory() async {
  final path = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  final myDataResource = HttpNetworkResource(
    url: serverurl +
        "classes/subCategory?limit=40",
    parser: (contents) => json.decode(contents),
    headers: header,
    cache: FileResource(File('$path/subcategoryall.json')),
    maxAge: Duration(minutes: 10),
    strategy: CacheStrategy.cacheFirst,
  );
  final myData = await myDataResource.get();
  return subcategory.fromJson(myData);
}

//grid view
FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchallsubcategory(),
           
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
           return snapshot.hasData ? GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
                        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int) {
                          return Card(
                            child: 
                           CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl : snapshot.data.results[int].image),
                          );
                        }
            ) :CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
```

Comment: You got any solution ?
I am facing the same.

Comment: Mr.saroj i am not sure if you still online here , but i have the same issue .. if you could provide me with the answer if you got an one .. i am gonna be so thankful for you , best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the same kind of app. I found *NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()* very helpful for scrollable image gridview. I hope the following code snippet helps you.

```js
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 10, // Set as you want or you can remove it also.
                maxHeight: double.infinity,
              ),
              child: Container(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount:
                      MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                          ? 3
                          : 4,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  childAspectRatio: .6,
                  children: thumbUrls
                      .map((urlThumb) => Card(
                            child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) {
                                        return new FullScreenImagePage(wallpapers[urlThumb]);//Map wallpaper = {url_thumb : [id, url_image]}
                                      })),
                                  child: new Image.network(
                                    urlThumb,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```